# Why open 123/udp in both directions?

Tags: firewall, ntp

When using an NTP server in an environment with a firewall, it is common to open 123/udp in both directions. So my question is, why is it necessary to open it in both directions?

For example, when synchronizing time from an NTP client to an NTP server, it seems to me that opening only in the outbound direction from the NTP client to the NTP server is not a problem. However, many websites indicate that the inbound direction should also be opened. Is the communication sequence different between NTP servers and between NTP servers and end devices such as PCs? I am honestly confused.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

> For example, when synchronizing time from an NTP client to an NTP server, it seems to me that opening only in the outbound direction from the NTP client to the NTP server is not a problem.

For clients, usually you *don't* need to explicitly open any ports inbound – you can rely on your stateful firewall remembering the ports that were used and automatically accepting the incoming reply packets.

However, you *do* need to make sure that nothing is explicitly blocking inbound packets on port 123 (which sometimes happens when ISPs try to mitigate DoS attacks and/or prevent customers from accidentally running open NTP servers).

In addition to "client/server", NTP also has a "symmetric" (peer-to-peer) mode. Somewhat unusually, older NTP versions use port numbers to determine which mode is being used – clients talking to servers use an ephemeral source port, but peers in symmetric mode use 123 as the source port – so inbound replies will likewise have 123 as the destination port.

In general, basic SNTP clients would use the "client/server" mode while full servers would use "symmetric active" mode. However, e.g. the built-in Windows NTP client (w32tm) appears to always use symmetric mode even though it's just doing a simple update, probably because it's still the same codebase as the NTP server running on AD domain controllers. (Similarly, PCs running ntpd might be configured to use symmetric mode.)

This means that with most Windows PCs (and possibly other NTP clients as well), the inbound replies from NTP servers to the PC will have 123 *as the destination port* and may be accidentally blocked by stateless ACLs which think that those are actually inbound queries.

Comment: Does this mean that inbound communication from an NTP server to a PC could be accidentally blocked because the destination port number is "123"? And if the number is dynamically assigned, such as 55555, is there no possibility of being blocked?

Comment: It could and I've seen several cases of that done. (Linux PCs being able to use NTP, but Windows PCs mysteriously not receiving any replies, and it always turned out to be a port-123 firewall rule.) Dynamically assigned ports are usually chosen from the "ephemeral" range, so they generally don't collide with any service worth blocking (as service ports are typically chosen from a lower range). Not to say that it can't happen – e.g. port 51413 might sometimes be blocked because it's the default port in many BitTorrent clients – but it's far less likely to happen.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In summary, normally it is not a problem if only outbound communication is allowed. However, if the system uses 123 as the source port number, like Windows, it may be accidentally blocked during inbound. Is that correct?